# How to use rolling function to compare the elements

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use `pandas` `rolling` function to compare whether the first element is smaller than the second one. I think the following codes should work:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,10,10), columns=['temperature'])
df.rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: x[0] < x[1])
```

but it does not work. Instead, I got an error message:

```
ValueError: 0 is not in range
```

Does anyone know what caused the issue?

**Update:**
I know I can use the `diff` function, but what I really want to do is something like this

```
df.rolling(window=3).apply(lambda x: x[0] < x[1] < x[2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the x[n] with x.iloc[n] should work (using positional indexing)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,10,10), columns=['temperature'])
df['increasing'] = df.rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] < x.iloc[1])
```

```
   temperature  increasing
0            8         NaN
1            9         1.0
2            0         0.0
3            3         1.0
4            8         1.0
5            7         0.0
6            7         0.0
7            8         1.0
8            7         0.0
9            6         0.0
```

Why?:

The value of 'x' in your lambda function looks something like this:

**first iteration:**

index   temperature
0            8
1            9

**second iteration:**

index   temperature
1            9
2            0

**third iteration:**

index   temperature
2            0
3            3

The first iteration works because the index 0 and 1 are available (so `x[0] < x[1]` works fine). However, in the second iteration, the index 0 isn't available and x[0] fails with your ValueError. My solution uses positional indexing (with .iloc) and ignores those index values (see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html).

This is also why your code works fine with two rows e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,10,2), columns=['temperature'])
df.rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: x[0] < x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, what you want to achieve if determining if the temperature is greater that the previous one?

You could use `diff`:

```
df['temperature'].diff().gt(0)
```

To check consecutive increases:

```
N = 3  # 3 consecutive values are increasing (= 2 increases)
df['increases2'] = df['temperature'].diff().gt(0).rolling(N-1).sum().eq(N-1)
```

example:

```
>>> df['increases'] = df['temperature'].diff().gt(0)
>>> df['increases2'] = df['temperature'].diff().gt(0).rolling(N-1).sum().eq(N-1)

   temperature  increases  increases2
0            7      False       False
1            7      False       False
2            9       True       False
3            1      False       False
4            7       True       False
5            0      False       False
6            6       True       False
7            9       True        True
8            9      False       False
9            7      False       False
```

Comment: What I want to do is something like this: `df.rolling(window=3).apply(lambda x: x[0] < x[1] < x[2])`

Comment: @Michael then add a `rolling` after: `df['temperature'].diff().gt(0).rolling(2).sum().eq(2)`